# check if condition, if statement is assigned as string variable - jquery|| javascript

Tags: javascript

I am struggling the following issue in jQuery or java script.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 6;
var str = "" + a + "==" + b + "";//(a==b)
if (str) {
  alert('true');
}
else {
   alert('false');
}
```

This result is always true, I am new to jQuery and Javascript.

Comment: What's exactly the question ?

Comment: If you want to test if a is equal to b, use `var str = a==b;`.

Comment: hi dystroy, I stored the condition in variable but it does not support to if statement in jQuery.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with JQuery, and I *think* evaluating a string as "if (str)" would only evaluate that it existed, you aren't actually evaluating the contents of the string "a == b"

Comment: You can use eval (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to interpret strings as code, but that's always an ugly practice.

Comment: You can learn about non-Boolean values in `if` statements [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp).

Comment: @OlivierH not only it's an ugly practice, but it's also unsafe, slow and prone to mistakes. If your favourite javascript reference doesn't tell you this (they don't), perhaps you should switch to a better one. Say, MDN.

Comment: @NobleMushtak that's not a good source by any means. I suggest codecademy, MDN, learn.jquery.com...

Comment: What's wrong with W3Schools? I use those (except for learn.jquery.com), too, but W3Schools seem just as good and that particular article seems to explain this quite well.

Comment: @JanDvorak Why are you so upset with w3schools ? I don't expect from a reference to tell me how to code, or what are good practices or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply try it like this:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 6;
if (a==b) {
  alert('true');
}
else {
   alert('false');
}
```

and if you need to get the value in a variable then try like this:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 6;
var str = (a==b);//(a==b)
if (str) {
  alert('true');
}
else {
   alert('false');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're evaluating a string as a boolean. When you assign `var str = "" + a + "==" + b + "";//(a==b)` you are, as your assignment seems to realize (by the fact that you called it `str`), creating a string. `if (str)` will *always* evaluate to `true` if that string is non-empty. What I think you want to do is `if (a==b)`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 6;
if (a==b) {
        alert('true');
}
else {
     alert('false');
}
```